# Deploying Android App Engine in the web (not locally)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, adt

I created simple Android App which sends a Person object to Android App Engine.

It works great locally: I can see all my records : `http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/datastore?kind=MessageData` but now I want to upload it to real google cloud. What I suppose to do?

I have my google cosnole: https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~boazeriasciana?authuser=0&redirected=true&utm_referrer=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.pl%2F

Where to look for my records? Is there any tutorial for THIS step?

These are my classes:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you already created your project on [app engine](https://console.developers.google.com/), all you need to do is check the configuration on your config xml file and deploy from the console.

If you are using Maven for building your code, check [this resource](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading), if you are using Gradle, you can read from step 6 on from [this endpoints example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-codelab-android).

In any case it all comes down to checking your XML file to check that config is ok and executing the command to deploy your server.

Maven:mvn appengine:update

Gradle:./gradlew todoTxtBackend:appengineUpdate